# how to fix Image view background and src?

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

i want a grid item like this: [image]

i tried to make a grid view item with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridImage"
        android:layout_width="233dp"
        android:layout_height="197dp"

        android:background="@drawable/breakfast_background"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" >

        </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alertCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:paddingLeft="25dip"
        android:paddingTop="18dip"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_TableName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

but background of image is not showing properly.

please suggest.

Comment: The image view is sized by its source, not by its background

Comment: Thanks but what is the solution ? i need a frame and image should be replaced dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you should use 2 ImageView instead of one :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="233dp"
    android:layout_height="197dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/shaped_breakfast_background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/frameImage"
    android:layout_width="233dp"
    android:layout_height="197dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/frame" />
```

with shaped_breakfast_background.xml in your drawable/ folder, being a shape (look up android res shape) that will take your image and round the corners by the same radius as your frame.
I admit I never tried it.
One drawback is : using bitmaps inside xml resources doesn't give you access to all the interesting scaleTypes ImageView handles (centerInside, centerCrop and so on), which might be a problem

However, if using a shape doesn't solve your problem you could of course use a breakfast_background already shaped the same way as your frame, this would save you a lot of time. And you could then get along with your "1 ImageView" solution.